# Scoped-search RAILS - unexpected end ofkeyword end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, search

I dont think iam opening any function... except in the search bar.. i cant find where iam not closing it... or is there any additional parameters i didnt  put?

i already restarted my sever this time...

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scoped_search on: [:name1, :name2]
end
```

search.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="section-title">
  <h1>List of users</h1>
        <div class="row">
  <%= form_tag( search_users_path, :method => 'GET' ) do%>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <%=text_field_tag "q", '', :placeholder => "Search", :value => params[:q] ,class:"form-control"%>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <%=submit_tag 'Find' ,class:"form-control"%>
  </div>
    <%end%>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
  <%if @users.nil?%>
  Please enter your search
      <%else%>
      <%if @users.size == 0 %>
      Could not be found
      <%else%>
        there are <%= pluralize(@users.total_entries,"user")%></strong> on <strong>"<%=params[:q] %>"</strong> <%render @users%>
    <%end%>

  <%=render 'users'%>

      <ul class="pager">
        <%= will_paginate @users %>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

users_controller.html.erb

```
class UsersController < InheritedResources::Base
layout 'guest'
  def search
    @users = User.paginate( :page => params[:page], :per_page => 9 )
    flash[:notice] = " "
  end
 end
```

application trace

```
app/views/users/search.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
app/views/users/search.html.erb:25: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the closing <% end %> to the if statement which has a nested if statement. Using a code formatter and proper indentation really helps finding missing end tags. I've added the missing end tag below.

```
<% if @users.nil? %>
  Please enter your search
<% else %>
  <% if @users.size == 0 %>
    Could not be found
  <% else %>
    there are <%= pluralize(@users.total_entries,"user")%></strong> on <strong>"<%=params[:q] %>"</strong> <%render @users%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The stack trace does a pretty good job of indicating where the error might be. In this case it's printed

```
app/views/users/search.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
```

so you can start by looking in that erb file around line 23.

Comment: Your the best dude THX~~ (>.<)!!... my previous project didnt have the <%end%> still worked... mustve missed it somewhere